# How to get grunt-connect work with livereload

Tags: grunt-contrib-connect

I have this config:

```
connect: {
            develop: {
                options: {
                    livereload: 35729,
                    hostname: '*',
                    port: 8000,
                    open: {
                        target: 'http://localhost:<%= connect.develop.options.port %>/src',
                        appName: 'Google Chrome'
                    },
                }
            }

        },
```

I start it and then 'watch' `grunt connect:develop watch`, but nothing gets 'reloaded'.

It looks like grunt-connect is properly injecting script into HTML cause i Have:

```
<script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></script>
```

But 
I get error in browser:

```
GET http://localhost:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Comment: Can you share your `watch` config?

Comment: not anymore - as a solution i moved from 'connect' to 'browser-sync' and it works perfectly